# How does PCI-Express work at a software level?

Tags: pci-express

At a software level, how do you communicate with a PCIe card?

(I realise only the OS has to care about such details, but I'm overly curious...)

I can *imagine* two possible ways it *could* work:

- Cards slot into a bus. To send a message to a card, you have to explicitly construct a message packet in software, tell the bus controller where you put it, and then the bus controller will use DMA read the message package and send it onto the bus. The bus controller fires an interrupt when the message has finished sending. The bus controller uses DMA to store incoming messages into main memory, and fires an interrupt when it finishes receiving one. The CPU must now parse the message in software to figure out who sent it and what it says.
- Cards slot into a bus. Each card maps directly into the address space of the CPU. The bus controller generates the necessary message packets (either in hardware or firmware) to make it appear that on-card memory is just like any other memory. The CPU just accesses memory addresses.

The question is, which of these models describes how PCIe *actually* works?

Comment: They use device drivers. See [1. How To Write Linux PCI Drivers — The Linux Kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/PCI/pci.html)

Comment: [operating system - how drivers work (e.g. PCIe and USB) - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46157728/how-drivers-work-e-g-pcie-and-usb)

Comment: [PCI driver programming guide - Windows drivers | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/pci/)